# create react app not picking up .env files?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using [create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to bootstrap my app.

I have added two `.env` files `.env.development` and `.env.production` in the root.

My `.env.development` includes:

```
API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api
CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3005/callback
```

When I run my app using `react-scripts start` and console out `process.env` it spits out

```
{ NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: "" }
```

I've tried different things, but its just not picking up the veriables in my development file, what am I doing wrong?!

Directry structure is:

```
/.env.development
/src/index.js
```

Package.json script is:

```
"start": "export PORT=3005; npm-run-all --parallel server:start client:start",
    "client:start": "export PORT=3005; react-scripts start",
    "server:start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
```

**Edit:**

@jamcreencia correctly pointed out my variables [should be prefixed](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) with `REACT_APP`.

**Edit 2**

It works okay if I name the file `.env` but not if I use `.env.development` or `.end.production`

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file ?

Comment: `process.env` is something that the back-end (Node or whatever you're using) can read. The front-end bundle has no idea what `process.env` is as it runs in the browser. You can configure webpack to pass it in the bundle when bundling, or even easier you can pass it from the back-end in the index file you're rendering as a global variable.

Comment: probably not the case, but i have run into this a couple of times and the problem i found is that when my computer is using a lot of memory i don't get my .env variable loaded. I use ubuntu 16.4. try loading the varible from the terminal `react-scripts start API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3005/callback` if you still don't see them i'd restart my system to lower memory usage and try again usually this resolves it for me.

Comment: @RaulRene create-react-app handles .env out of the box for you not need for further config

Comment: `.env ` is the file name, not the ending! Don't make the mistake of calling your file `secret.env` or similar, that won't work!

Answer (score 631, accepted):

With create react app, you need to prefix `REACT_APP_` to the variable name. ex:

```ini
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api
REACT_APP_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3005/callback
```

**  **Make sure your .env file is in the root directory, not inside src fold**er.

CRA Docs on [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/):

> *Note*: You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name

Comment: This is vital. i missed it but yeah it won't work with the prefix

Comment: This works when I use `.env` but not for `.env.development` or `.env.production` ?

Comment: @shenku Did you manage to find out why it works only with `.env` and not with `.env.development` and `env.production`

Comment: For Devs doing front-end work, because you don’t have NodeJs in the browser, you're going to need webpack... meh

Comment: even prefix with REACT_APP_ doesn't help me. I have .env file on the root folder but it doesn't help me.

Comment: I stopped my development server and started it again and saw that my Env variables are picked up. I have 2 files `.env` and `.env.local` in my root folder.

Comment: Vital bit of information after the change, restart the server as I had the same issue!

Comment: It works fine when I rename all the variables with the prefix **REACT_APP_** and make sure that all the variables are present in each environment file.

Comment: After several minutes of trying, I finally tried restarting my react server which works out fine.

Comment: Also, if you have been using .envrc in other projects, make sure *not* to include export before the environment vars - stupid thing to overlook in a copy-paste

Comment: `.env ` is the file name, not the ending! Don't make the mistake of calling your file `secret.env` or similar, that won't work!

Answer (score 172):

Make sure your .env file is in the root directory, not inside src folder.

Comment: Although, while reading the documentation I saw it should be in the root directory, I still managed to add my .env file in the src folder...(facepalm) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, it didn't work when inside src folder but it worked after moving into root folder in  version 3.4.3

Answer (score 77):

Had this same problem!  The solution was to close the connection to my node server (you can do this with CTRL + C).  Then re-start your server with 'npm run start' and .env should work properly.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4485#issuecomment-443358588)

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use multiple environment like `.env.development`  `.env.production`

use [dotenv-cli package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli)

add `.env.development` and  `.env.production` in project root folder

and your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build-dev": "dotenv -e .env.development react-app-rewired build",
    "build-prod": "dotenv -e .env.production react-app-rewired build",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"   
},
```

then build according to environment like

```
npm run-script build-dev
```

Comment: is this `dotenv` or `dotenv-cli`?

Comment: Having different .env files for different environments is now also supported out of the box by create-react-app: [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used). No need to use dotenv explicitly (create-react-app actually uses it behind the scenes to handle environment variables)

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu, that syntax belongs to `dotenv-cli`, not `dotenv`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli

Comment: @AMS777 I'm using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm not [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli)

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu, I wanted to use `dotenv` but got an error. I checked the documentation but didn't find that `-e` option for the command line. However I found it on the `dotenv-cli` documentation. That's why I was saying. I'm finally using `env-cmd`, not to have `dotenv` and `dotenv-cli` installed at the same time, which may lead to confusion.

Comment: @AMS777 idk that i was using this over year ago. do you want me to update the answer with dotenv-cli

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu, I think a mention to it would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

I was having the same problem, but it was because I had my **.env** file in YAML format instead of JS.

It was

```
REACT_APP_API_PATH: 'https://my.api.path'
```

but it needed to be

```
REACT_APP_API_PATH = 'https://my.api.path'
```

Comment: Such a simple yet good spot.  I had done the same and couldn't see the wood for the trees.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this! I was searching all day not noticing this slight error :)

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Ahhh I'm embarassed. +1

Answer (score 19):

For people who apply all those answers above and didn't work just restart the terminal of npm start, stop the live server and run it again and it will work because it works for me

Comment: Worked as a charm! Thanks

Comment: Stopping the live server and restarting is a critical step. This needs to be included in the top voted answer!

Answer (score 16):

Regarding [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd). As per VMois's kind [post on gitHub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6995), *env-cmd* has been updated ( version 9.0.1 as of writing ), environment variables will work as follows on your *React* project:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:local": "env-cmd -f ./.env.production.local npm run build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f ./.env.production npm run build"
  }
```

In your *package.json* file.

Comment: Thank you so much, this comment saved me. The create-react-app documentation hasn't updated this, so I was figuring out what is wrong

Comment: You totally saved me here.  I was spinning on this thing.  Thank you

Comment: somebody give this guy a medal

Comment: Thanks for this even in blogs they didn't give this commands properly

Comment: Thanks, you solve my main problem regarding .env

Answer (score 15):

1- Make sure .env file is based your react app root directory

2- for react app you need to prefix REACT_APP_ to the variable name. ex: REACT_APP_API_URL

3- kill server and npm start again after .env file modify

Comment: Just for anyone coming to this the  prefix REACT_APP_  is very important else it wont work

Comment: `kill server and npm start again after .env file modify` this worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For this purpose there is [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) module. Install via npm `npm i env-cmd` then in your `package.json` file in `scripts` section:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false env-cmd .env.production react-scripts build",
  }
```

In your project root you have to create two files with the same env variables but with different values:

```
.env.development
.env.production
```

Then exclude them from public. For this in your `.gitignore` file add two lines:

```
.env.development
.env.production
```

So this is a proper way to use different env variables for dev and prod.

Comment: try to use full path, like: ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd

Comment: but I do not recommend the approach in my answer. Now I know that react gives build in mechanic to work with .env

Answer (score 8):

While working with `.env` file, be it frontend or backend.

- **Whenever you modify the `.env` file**, you must restart the respective server for the changes to take effect in the application.
- Hot reloading doesn't read changes from `.env` file.

Answer (score 6):

`Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if they were declared locally in your JS files. By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other environment variables starting with REACT_APP_.`

Reference: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

that doc creates confusion.

So you actually need to put prefix `REACT_APP_` within the .env to make it work.

And make sure that you restart the test/dev/prod server because the .env content change was loaded on the build stage.

Answer (score 5):

If the `.env` file works but `.env.development` or `.env.production` don't, then create an empty `.env` file alongside those two. I don't know why but this works for me.

Answer (score 5):

when you get `undefined` from the environment file then just stop the terminal and restarts with `npm start` command.

Answer (score 4):

And remember not to have semi-colon after the API key in the env-file.

`REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'ae87cec695cc4heheh639d06c9274a';`

should be

`REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'ae87cec695cc44heheh1639d06c9274a'`

that was my error

Answer (score 3):

I made the silly mistake of naming my file `secret.env` because that's how I always did it in Node.js.
After changing the name to `.env`, restarting the terminal, and running `npm start` again, everything worked like a charm

Comment: I dont know how i missed this.  Asking the wrong questions i guess.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For any VS Code users, be aware that the `.env.local` env file is auto-sourced, but also auto-ignored from search results when you do a project wide search for MY_ENV_VAR(probably due to it being git ignored by default). This means that if you have `MY_ENV_VAR=` in your `.env.local` like me and forgot about it, it'll break things and you'll spend 15 mins being very confused.

Answer (score 2):

Was struggling for a good hour before I noticed my kind IDE added an import:

```
import * as process from "process";
```

just remove it and you're fine, if that's your case as well.

Answer (score 2):

After you add `.env` file, you need to

- restart your application
- kill the server
- run `npm start` again

And it should work

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue that I wasn't able to access .env variable in App.js.
and I had solved the problem use create correct .env file.

in my case I was copy file from different OS and use in ubuntu system
so just I did "sudo touch .env" and added my variables and restart app again then it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any value back as well. For some reason, I thought the environment file should be dev.env, qa.env etc. Actually, it's just ".env". That's that. In case some else makes this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

create-react does not supports hot reload feature .env files since they are not Javascript. So, when you change the env files make sure to manually start your server to see the effect of new changes.

In my case, a manual restart of the server worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to install env-cmd and after that in my package.JSON add the following line of code

```
"scripts": {
"start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start ",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add process.env.

It looks like this

```
const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

first step:

**in your .env.local file add REACT_APP_your_API_key in this way**

second step:

**Add your config file `${process.env.REACT_APP_Your_API_key}`**

the third step:

**must restart your React App and then Test whether it works**.

mainly, I forget the last step

Comment: Do you mean `${process.env.REACT_APP_Your_API_key}` (`.` instead of `_` after `process.env`)?

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions above worked for you, give these potential solutions a shot:

1. Make sure all the `import` statements within the file that is requiring defined environmental variables are being imported from the local project and not some other project(VSCode wrongly autocompleted some of my `import` statements in this manner)
2. Try exiting your current Terminal instance and running the app in a new instance

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 3 steps:

1. Install dotenv

   `npm install dotenv --save`
2. Add following line in your code:

   `require('dotenv').config()`
3. Create a `.env` file in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable starts with `REACT_APP_` (this is a must when using Create React App).

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of react app like vite react-app and normal react app.

Do the following steps first:

A. **npm install dotenv --save**

B. Add following line into your js file where you require environmental variables:
**require('dotenv').config()**

C. In both kind of react app the .env file should be outside the source folder and should be right next to .gitignore and package.json file.

Second,

1. If you are using vite react app, then write your environmental variables as follows where **VITE_** is compulsory
   `VITE_API_KEY=28y4nkrasdhew`

   Now to access this, use the following syntax in your javascript file as
   `import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY`
2. Or if you are using normal react app, then write your environmental variables as follows where **REACT_APP_** is compulsory
   `REACT_APP_API_KEY=28y4nkrasdhew`

   Now to access this, use the following syntax in your javascript file as
   `process.env.VITE_API_KEY`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply restarting the application wasn't enough to access the environment variables. What worked for me was:

1. Stopping the application (using Ctrl+C in the terminal)
2. Rebuilding it with **npm run build**
3. Starting it again with **npm start**

After this env vars were successfully loaded.

Answer (score -3):

As of latest react-scripts (3.2.0) it's a simple as putting say

```
PORT=4000
BROWSER=none
```

in your .env or .env.development file (..etc) which is supposed to be in the root folder.

It will NOT work with then REACT_APP prefix (the docs are outdated I guess) and it does NOT require any extra npm packages (react-scripts already includes dotenv 6.2.0)

Comment: This is false. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/f875bb0c8444720f5eac1b24822e10421b9f1202/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js#L71