# importing env variable react front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, environment-variables

I have bootstrapped an app using `create-react-app`. I have a token that I don't wish to push to GitHub.

I have ran `yarn add dontenv` and then tried to import the env variable to my `App.js` file.

My code looks like this

**.env**

```
TOKEN=**************
```

Then my `app.js` file looks like this:

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
require('dotenv').config();

const App = props => {
    console.log(process.env.token);
    return <p>Test</p>
}
```

`process.env.token` is `undefined`. Can anyone advise how to use token in the front end or how I should do this using a bootstrapped create-react-app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide API key in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699820/how-do-i-hide-api-key-in-create-react-app)

Comment: i dont remember, i asked this question over 4 years ago, and there is a popular and accepted answer below so I imagine that answered my question @Malcolm

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You don't need `dotenv` (and I doubt that library will work at runtime in a client-side application anyway).

[`create-react-app` actually provides this functionality out of the box](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env), assuming you're using `react-scripts@0.5.0` or higher.

The steps are as follows:

- Create a `.env` file in the root of your project.
- Add a variable, starting with the prefix `REACT_APP_`.
- Access it via `process.env`.

That second bit is the important part - to avoid you exposing variables by accident, `create-react-app` forces you to use a prefix as a way of saying "yes, I know what I'm doing".

If you're not intending to push the file to source control (which you shouldn't be, if it's got secret keys in!), then using an `.env.local` file is more idiomatic - that requires `react-scripts@1.0.0` or higher, though.

Comment: Note: You need to restart your server after making these corrections

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA took me sometime to figure that out, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

for anybody that does not get this to work, try this

if you want git to ignore it you can create a `.env.local` file and git will ignore it. Look at your .gitignore file and you will find the `.env.local``

1. create `.env.local` file in your root folder
2. Open your `.env.local`
3. IMPORTANT, all your environment variables MUST start with `REACT_APP_`
4. Create an environment variables `REACT_APP_BASE_URL`
5. Restart your application (kill it)
6. To access environment variables you write `process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL`

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. ".env.local" or ".env" they both work fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
 - Create .env file in root folder

 - Open to .env file

     --> REACT_APP_API_KEY= API KEY
    **NOTE** starting with the prefix REACT_APP_ (IMPORTANT)

 - Access it use process.env
  eg  const  {REACT_APP_API_KEY,REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID} = process.env

 - And use with template string
 eg emailjs.send(`${REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID}`,`${REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID}`, values, `${REACT_APP_API_KEY}` )
      .then((response) => {
         console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
      }, (err) => {
         console.log('FAILED...', err);
      });


When you do any changes or need to create at .env file don't forget to restart  
appliction "npm start"
```

hopefully, you'll find this helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use any code logic for this purpose. You have to use different .env files for production and development if you want to serv different values for different environments. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53029799/10220619)