# Need help declaring enviornment variables on React app using Yarn

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, yarnpkg

I'm trying add an env variable to my app without success:

- I did `yarn add dotenv`
- added an .env file in root with `URL='https://mywebsite.com'`
- added to my app.js:

  `const dotenv = require("dotenv")
   dotenv.config()
  console.log(process.env.URL);`

and got `undefined`.

In my package.json I have `"start": "./.env && react-scripts start",`

And I deleted `yarn.lock` to get it into effect. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if someone has a better solution but what worked was from this thread [reactjs + yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378337/create-react-app-not-picking-up-env-files)

1. `.env` file and change `URL='https://mywebsite.com'` to `REACT_APP_URL='https://mywebsite.com`
2. `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_URL)`

Hope someone has a better solution

Comment: That’s the preferred way to do it, you don’t even need dotenv, check the docs https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/