# React, use JSON as env

Tags: reactjs

I have a shared JSON on vault for a React app like this one:

```
{
    "REACT_APP_SOME_ENV": "some value",
    "REACT_APP_SOME_ENV2": "some value2",
}
```

How could I use it as the `.env` file?

Right now I'm just copy pasting each value as a regular `.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_SOME_ENV=some value
REACT_APP_SOME_ENV2=some value2
```

But that's not the idea, that file changes a lot.

Any npm tools or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create react app not picking up .env files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378337/create-react-app-not-picking-up-env-files)

Comment: No, that's totally different. I just want to read the env values from a json, not from the .env

Answer (score 1):

To add values from a JSON to your environment just `require()` the JSON file and assign its values to `process.env`

Example env.json

```json
{
    "REACT_APP_SOME_ENV": "some value",
    "REACT_APP_SOME_ENV2": "some value2"
}
```

In your index.js file:

```js
const envJSON = require("./env.json");

Object.assign(process.env, envJSON);
```

Comment: But I wont add to package.json the enviroment var, I want to use a file called (for instance) .env.json add it to .gitignore, and then put a json there, so I want to read that json instead the default .env file. Other wise, I will keep converting manually the json to .env

Comment: @pmiranda check now

Comment: But I can't put in .gitignore `package.json`. My idea is to had that json ignored