# Setting environment variables with cross-env in package.json for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, environment-variables, create-react-app

I'm making a client side React app and want to set an environment variable at runtime. My `package.json` contains

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env BUILD_TYPE=dev react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

and in my app I have

```
let api_base_url;
if (process.env.BUILD_TYPE === 'dev') {
  api_base_url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_DEV_SERVER_URL
  console.log("dev build");
} else {
  api_base_url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER_URL;
  console.log("not a dev build");
}
```

When I run my app using `npm run start`, first I see `cross-env BUILD_TYPE=dev react-scripts start` at the command line, then in the console I see `not a dev build` and it's using my non-dev server address.  What am I doing wrong?

If it matters, I'm on Debian in WSL 2 on Windows 11.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Prefix with `REACT_APP_`

Comment: Use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` for this.

Comment: Ah thanks - that was driving me nuts. Is there a reason I should prefer `NODE_ENV`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create react app not picking up .env files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378337/create-react-app-not-picking-up-env-files)

Comment: Just because it's set for you automatically by CRA (see linked docs), so why add unnecessary complexity of another env var? It's the standard way to do this.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you're baking both API URLs _and_ the thing which says which one to actually use in at build time. Just bake in one URL, or configure at runtime.

Comment: Good point. Check out [environment specific env files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used). That way you just reference `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` in your code, and depending on dev vs. prod it will pick up the right one automatically.