# why process.env doesn't work in app.js file but works in webpack.config.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, .env

why process.env doesn't work in app.js file but works in webpack.config.js? I have my own webpack that I created myself. It was not created with CRA

the version so it is correct to deduce? Or is there any way to get it out? Or is it better not to drive at all? since it seems to me that this is also not correct, since the env file should be in the exception and on the server, when loading, probably nothing will be known about the version ...

I want to output the version to the console so I can see the webpack version. But I can't do it even though I made the necessary settings. if I output data in webpack, then everything works correctly if I output data in a simple js file, erroneous errors. in general, I want to make the version visible on the server after the build, and I want to do it in this way, you can simply output console.log, but this seems like the wrong solution console.log('ver 1.74.2')

[image]

[image]

---

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.scss";

const onClickEvent = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("You Clicked Me!");
};

const App = () => {
  console.log(process.env.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION);
  return (
    <div className={styles.content}>
      <div className={styles.label}>OWN WEBPACK</div>
      <button className={styles.btn} onClick={onClickEvent}>
        Click Me 
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
console.log(process.env.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION);

module.exports = {
  entry: { myAppName: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js") },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: production ? "[name].[contenthash].js" : "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          production ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: !production,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: !production,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".scss"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new Dotenv(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Webpack & React",
      template: "./src/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: production ? "[name].[contenthash].css" : "[name].css",
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      "process.env.MY_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_ENV),
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    hot: true,
  },
  mode: production ? "production" : "development",
};
```

---

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node server/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development test=$TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:watch": "NODE_ENV=development node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
```

---

```
//server/index.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.log('in development.');
} else {
    console.log('in production.');
}

/* App Config */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));


/* Server Initialization */
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server initialized on: http://localhost:${port} // ${new Date()}`));
```

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create react app not picking up .env files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378337/create-react-app-not-picking-up-env-files)

Comment: this answer is not suitable because I have my own webpack and not automatically generated

Comment: the solution for create react app is not suitable there. I have my own webpack from scratch

Comment: You should read up on what it does, it copies `process.env` variables from build time (webpack config) into a plain JS so you can access `process.env` available at runtime

Comment: so I won't be able to access this variable?   console.log(process.env.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION);

Comment: or can I get it by setting it up correctly?

Comment: I updated the question yesterday and attached the code to git, you can test it

Answer (score 1):

Change your env variable to `REACT_APP_TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION` then reload your app.

React env variables must start with `REACT_APP_` prefix. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I have a webpack that I myself created from scratch

Comment: this answer is not suitable because I have my own webpack and not automatically generated

Comment: the answer suits you only for those who create a project using CRA. my project was completely assembled manually, so it does not fit here.